# Changing expression tree at run time

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# expressions trees.

I've an expression tree being passed to a method as below:

```
private void MyMethod(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression exp, string param)
```

I need to be able to tweak this exp and add two AND clauses based on the param value at runtime.
How do I achieve this please?

An example to call this method is:

```
var temp= MyOtherMethod(cellValue.ExpressionObj, columnName);
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes,I meant Expression<T>.Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of a call to this method.

Comment: The most important thing to understand is *you never change an expression tree*.  You make a *new tree* that has the characteristics that you want; you are free to use parts of an old tree if that helps you, because *the old tree will not be changed*.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [ExpressionVisitor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Good example how to use it can be found in [Dissecting Linq Expression Trees - Part 2](https://www.simplethread.com/dissecting-linq-expression-trees-part-2/) blog post.

Expressions are immutable and you need to return new expression back to caller to use the altered one.

Long story short:

```
private Expression MyMethod(Expression<MyClass> exp, string param) {
    if(param == "something") {
        var visitor = new CustomVisitor(); /// You should implement one based on your needs
        return visitor.Visit(exp);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public class AndAlsoVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node) {
        // Make it lambda expression
        var lambda = node as LambdaExpression;

        // This should never happen
        if (node != null) {
            // Create property access 
            var lengthAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                lambda.Parameters[0],
                lambda.Parameters[0].Type.GetProperty("Length")
            );

            // Create p.Length >= 10
            var cond1 = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(lengthAccess, Expression.Constant(10));
            // Create p.Length >= 3
            var cond2 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(lengthAccess, Expression.Constant(3));
            // Create p.Length >= 10 && p.Length >= 3
            var merged = Expression.AndAlso(cond1, cond2);
            // Merge old expression with new one we have created
            var final = Expression.AndAlso(lambda.Body, merged);
            // Create lambda expression
            var result = Expression.Lambda(final, lambda.Parameters);

            // Return result
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I reviewed your change and the answer is still the same. You should inherit from ExpressionVisitor class and override VisitLambda method. There you should change the expression.